# Salesforce Marketing Cloud mass email send

Tags: salesforce-marketing-cloud

I want help from someone regarding the mass email send via Salesforce Marketing Cloud.

For example, I want to send emails to 5000 customers daily. It is a newsletter. Each days the email contents will change. There are 4 dynamic variables in my newsletter. First Name, Last Name, Email and Message.

Which is the option to send mass emails via Salesforce Marketing Cloud?

There are different options like use Data Extension, List, Triggered Send. I used triggered send (I am using PHP fuelSDK ) and it is not sending all the 5000 emails quickly (when I created a triggered send I have selected Email, List, etc). I am calling the Triggered send api 5000 times to send to each emails (It is taking more than 1.30 hours to complete). Also it is not sending email to all the 5000 email addresses. Some failure response I am getting like "Error Code: 24 - Subscriber was excluded by List Detective". I understand this. Some emails I can see "Successfully sent" response in the log. But when I check it in tracking section, those emails are not there. I don't know what is happening here.

Can any one help me to understand the problem?

Comment: Hello @VPN, I would recommend taking your question over to the Salesforce Stack Exchange where you will likely get a larger audience - https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marketing-cloud

Comment: Hello, Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the List detective error for certain domains that are by default blocked by the standard list detective in SFMC (e.g. mail@, info@). That is why you would not be able to add those subscribers to your all subscribers' list if you try to and will get an error. To exclude these from the standard list view you have to create a case with SF and request that explicitly (https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000382509&type=1)

Cheers :)